# view cache fails when data is posted - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-1.3

I am using view caching in cakePHP 1.3, which is working fine. what I am trying to do it, I am also caching add & edit action.
1st time form is displaying properly but when I post data (form action for post is also same), so instead of saving data, its calling same cached view.

So is there any way where I can bypass cached view in case if data is posted.

Comment: You should never cache the 'edit' action; otherwise, you'll show data of the wrong record? Why are you caching those actions? Caching should imo be used for frequently accessed pages only (e.g. front-end of your website, homepage etc)

Comment: @thaJeztah I am developing an application & it has edit/add pages which  are not going to change for like months but we will be using them very often.  Can anybody atleast tell me where this checking of cached view is performed?

Comment: The edit/add pages will modify for *every 'item' you're going to edit* E.g. `pages/edit/1` will show different content than `pages/edit/2`. And *after each update*, the cached version of `pages/edit/1` will have to be updated as well. So I wonder if caching will give a lot of benefits.

Comment: hey @thaJeztah i have taken care of that part but problem is when I save/update data(post data), instead of calling action(where logic is defined) its again calling cached view. So i was wondering, if I could alter code in a such a way that if its just have to display form then from cached view is called and if its post data then action should be called. is this achievable?